# Developing Full CRUD Operations Using Modal Popup in ASP.NET Core MVC. But output showing "undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am developing Full CRUD Operations Using Modal Popup in ASP.NET Core MVC. But the output shows "undefined".Where I am wrong? I am giving my code below. I am trying to resolve it but not getting success.

### Here is my controller

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using reCRM.Models;

namespace reCRM.Controllers
{
    public class PropertyCategoryController : Controller
    {
        private readonly reCRMdbContext _context;

        public PropertyCategoryController(reCRMdbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult GetCategory()
        {
            var categories = _context.PropertyCategories.ToList();
            return Json(categories);
        }
    }
}
```

### my .cshtml file

```
@model reCRM.Models.PropertyCategory
@{
    ViewData["title"] = "Property Category";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutDashboard.cshtml";
}
<h3>@ViewData["title"]</h3>
<div class="btn btn-primary mb-2" id="btnAdd">Add Product Category</div>
<div class="container">
    <table class="table table-success table-striped table-hover table-responsive">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Category Name</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tblBody"></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/prodcategory.js"></script>
```

### JavaScript file

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    GetCategory();
});

/* Read Data */
function GetCategory() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/PropertyCategory/GetCategory',
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            console.log('Success: ', response);

            if (response == null || response == undefined || response.length == 0) {
                var object = '';
                object += '<tr>';
                object += '<td colspan="2">' + 'Category not available' + '</td>';
                object += '</tr>';
                $('#tblBody').html(object);
            } else {
                var object = '';
                $.each(response, function (index, item) {
                    object += '<tr>';
                    object += '<td>' + item.PropertyCategoryName + '</td>';
                    object += '<td> <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="Edit(' + item.category_id + ')"> Edit</a > <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="Delete(' + item.category_id + ')">Delete</a></td > ';
                    object += '</tr>';
                });
                $('#tblBody').html(object);
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            console.error('Error: ', status, error);
            alert('Unable to read the data');
        }
    });
}
```

### my model cs file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace reCRM.Models
{
    public partial class PropertyCategory
    {
        public PropertyCategory()
        {
            PropertyListings = new HashSet<PropertyListing>();
            PropertySubCategories = new HashSet<PropertySubCategory>();
        }

        [Key]
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Property Category Name")]
        public string PropertyCategoryName { get; set; } = null!;

        public virtual ICollection<PropertyListing> PropertyListings { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PropertySubCategory> PropertySubCategories { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[image]

I got above output. Where I am wrong?

Comment: if doesn't work then show us data  of `console.log('Success: ', response);`.

Comment: `+ item.category_id  +` - your cs model/class doesn't have a `public int category_id { get; set; }` - change to `+ item.CategoryId + `

Comment: console.log output is:--- Success: Array(3)
    {
        "categoryId": 1,
        "propertyCategoryName": "Apartment",
        "propertyListings": [],
        "propertySubCategories": []
    },
    {
        "categoryId": 2,
        "propertyCategoryName": "Villa",
        "propertyListings": [],
        "propertySubCategories": []
    },
    {
        "categoryId": 3,
        "propertyCategoryName": "Independent House",
        "propertyListings": [],
        "propertySubCategories": []
    }
]

Comment: changes item.category_id to  item.CategoryId .  Still no succcess

Comment: changes these two :  item.CategoryId to item.categoryId and PropertyCategoryName to propertyCategoryName and it is working now